# UNIX : Deleting all the lines containing string & number

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a `TXT` files with lines of about 1 Million.

```
#Test.txt
zs272
zs273
zs277
zs278
zs282
zs285
zs288
zs289
zs298
zs300
zs7
zsa
zsag
zsani179yukkie
zsani182zaide
zsaqgiw
zsb86581
zsbguepqtkcn
zscazn
zscfhlsv
zscgxadrwijl
zsclions111yuen
zscwqtk
zscz
zsder
zsdfdgdgg
```

I wanted to delete the line which has the numbers and keeping only strings.

I tried,

```
grep -v '^[1-9]' Test.txt > 1_Test.txt
```

Couldn't get the desired result.

Expected output:

```
#1_Test.txt
    zsa
    zsag
    zsbguepqtkcn
    zscazn
    zscfhlsv
    zscgxadrwijl
    zscwqtk
    zscz
    zsder
    zsdfdgdgg
```

Comment: Thanx dude ! edited the result !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/[0-9]/d' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

```
awk '!/[0-9]/' file
```

---

With bash:

```
while read -r line; do [[ ! $line =~ [0-9] ]] && printf "%s\n" "$line"; done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the start of the line anchor `^`.
 `^[1-9]` regex only matches the numbers 1-9 which exists at the start.

```
grep -v '[1-9]' Test.txt > 1_Test.txt
```

to work for all digits including 0.

```
grep -v '[0-9]' Test.txt > 1_Test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @avinash ! Fixed !

Answer (score 0):

A solution in AWK!

```
awk '!/[0-9]+/{print}' file
```